# Mixpanel events not sent

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mixpanel

I have created a simple react app, and I try to send some events to mixpanel.

However nothing is sent. No api requests are shown in network console, when mixpanel.track('test') is called.

when mixpanel.init('token') is called, I receive this response:
`{"notifications":[],"config":{"enable_collect_everything":false}}`

this is my index.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

let mixpanel = require('mixpanel-browser');
mixpanel.init('my-secret-token');

mixpanel.track('test');

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

I have initialized my react app by create-react-app, and installed mixpanel-browser module.

I also have created mixpanel project, and triple checked that token.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, it seems to have something to do with my chrome browser.
When using safari, everything works fine, but with chrome nothing is sent.

macOS: high sierra, 10.13.6 (17G65)
chrome version: 68.0.3440.106

Comment: not sure why this was marked correct. the reason events were not getting emitted from chrome may be due to "Do not track" setting enabled on the same

Comment: This answer shouldn't be marked as the correct answer. @comiventor 's answer is helpful. I had same issue and after disabling `Do not track` setting in Chrome browser resolved my problem, Thanks :)

Answer (score 14):

Anything that stops tracking can be the cause - Adblock is one possibility.

Another one is "Do not track" setting enabled on your browser.

There may be other plugins which you might have installed to avoid websites tracking you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer. I had alreday wasted 3hours on it. Tried all the SDKs . my fix was that i had to go to chrome and unselect Do not track option

Comment: or in mixpanel.init set ignore_dnt: true

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any adblocker?

I had the same issue and the problem was the uBlock chrome extension. Some adblockers prevent Mixpanel from loading on your page.
To avoid this, I moved all the important events to the backend.

Here you have the Mixpanel information about adblockers:

https://help.mixpanel.com/hc/en-us/articles/115004499463-Ad-Blockers-Affect-Mixpanel

Comment: No I don't have any adblocker, but I do have some other extensions. I haven't tried with different chrome versions, or without any extensions. Anyway I'm okay with safari.

Comment: Same problem here

Comment: I got the same issue when I tested it on chrome.